# Apache reverse proxy with cross origin (CORS): CentOS 7 / implement SSO (single sign on)

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy, splunk

I am using Apache(`2.4.23`) reserve proxy(`192.168.1.208`) in CentOS `7.2` to do crossing origin so that I could send cookies from one domain to the other.

Our application (location in `192.168.1.210`, using splunk Java sdk to sent request (`http://192.168.0.208/splunk`) to apache server (`192.168.0.208`). And apache reserver proxy will send request in turn to splunk server which listens to port `8000` in the same server. The purpose is to send cookies also to splunk server (`192.168.0.208:8000`) in order to make SSO. But I failed to send cookie to splunk server.

Our httpd.conf configuration is as follows:

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache"

Listen 80

# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
   User apache
   Group apache
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerName 192.168.1.208:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel debug
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
    Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

<location /api/move >
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</location>
```

httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Location "/splunk">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"

        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ssouser=([^;]+) [NC]
        RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%1]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE-USER %{RU}e

        ProxyPass http://192.168.1.208:8000/splunk
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.208:8000/splunk
    </location>
</VirtualHost>
```

In Splunk, I have server.conf and web.conf two configuation files in /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/ folder.

server.conf

```
[general]
trustedIP = 192.168.1.208
serverName = Splunk_Core_02
pass4SymmKey = $7$RRvdYDdIlj4P2geQdtHluTRb7OfvZhTFTZGJ7z5JiZAkJ6Q1at6j0Q==
sessionTimeout = 30s

[sslConfig]
sslPassword = $7$m6pB5a0PWFg64VlNZGgunhGElO3qLiAc6NrhfLO+tpX2jR7WC7qm1Q==

[lmpool:auto_generated_pool_download-trial]
description = auto_generated_pool_download-trial
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = download-trial

[lmpool:auto_generated_pool_forwarder]
description = auto_generated_pool_forwarder
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = forwarder

[lmpool:auto_generated_pool_free]
description = auto_generated_pool_free
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = free

[license]
active_group = Enterprise

[diskUsage]
minFreeSpace = 1024

[lmpool:test_splunk]
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = enterprise
```

web.conf

```
#   Version 7.2.4

[default]


[settings]
#SSO
SSOMode = permissive
trustedIP = 192.168.1.208
remoteUser = REMOTE-USER
tools.proxy.on = False

root_endpoint = /splunk

enableSplunkWebSSL = 0

httpport = 8000

mgmtHostPort = 127.0.0.1:8089

appServerPorts = 8065

splunkdConnectionTimeout = 30

enableSplunkWebClientNetloc = False

privKeyPath = $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/auth/splunkweb/privkey.pem
serverCert = $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/auth/splunkweb/cert.pem


sslVersions = tls1.2
cipherSuite = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ecdhCurves = prime256v1, secp384r1, secp521r1

# external UI URIs
userRegistrationURL = https://www.splunk.com/page/sign_up
updateCheckerBaseURL = https://quickdraw.splunk.com/js/
docsCheckerBaseURL = https://quickdraw.splunk.com/help


showProductMenu = False
productMenuLabel = My Splunk
showUserMenuProfile = False
productMenuUriPrefix = https://splunkcommunities.force.com

x_frame_options_sameorigin = True

remoteUserMatchExact = 0
remoteGroupsMatchExact = 0
remoteGroupsQuoted = True

allowSsoWithoutChangingServerConf = 0
static_endpoint = /static
static_dir = share/splunk/search_mrsparkle/exposed
testing_endpoint = /testing
testing_dir = share/splunk/testing

rss_endpoint = /rss
embed_uri =
embed_footer = splunk>
template_dir = share/splunk/search_mrsparkle/templates
module_dir = share/splunk/search_mrsparkle/modules
enable_gzip = True

use_future_expires = True

flash_major_version = 9
flash_minor_version = 0
flash_revision_version = 124

enable_proxy_write = True

js_logger_mode = None
js_logger_mode_server_end_point = util/log/js
js_logger_mode_server_poll_buffer = 1000
js_logger_mode_server_max_buffer = 100

ui_inactivity_timeout = 60

enable_insecure_login = True

simple_error_page = False

cacheBytesLimit = 4194304
cacheEntriesLimit = 16384
staticCompressionLevel = 9

enable_autocomplete_login = False

verifyCookiesWorkDuringLogin = True

login_content =

enabled_decomposers = plot

minify_js = True
minify_css = True

trap_module_exceptions = True
enable_pivot_adhoc_acceleration = True
pivot_adhoc_acceleration_mode = Elastic

jschart_test_mode = False
jschart_truncation_limit.chrome = 50000
jschart_truncation_limit.firefox = 50000
jschart_truncation_limit.safari = 50000
jschart_truncation_limit.ie11 = 50000
jschart_series_limit = 100
jschart_results_limit = 10000

choropleth_shape_limit = 10000

dashboard_html_allow_inline_styles = true
dashboard_html_allow_iframes = true

max_view_cache_size = 1000
pdfgen_is_available = 1
listenOnIPv6 = no

log.access_file = web_access.log
log.access_maxsize = 25000000
log.access_maxfiles = 5
log.error_maxsize = 25000000
log.error_maxfiles = 5
log.screen = True
request.show_tracebacks = True
engine.autoreload_on = False
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.sessions.timeout = 1
tools.sessions.restart_persist = True
tools.sessions.httponly = True
tools.sessions.secure = True
tools.sessions.forceSecure = False
response.timeout = 7200

tools.sessions.storage_type = file
tools.sessions.storage_path = var/run/splunk
tools.decode.on = True
tools.encode.on = True
tools.encode.encoding = utf-8

override_JSON_MIME_type_with_text_plain = True

job_min_polling_interval = 100
job_max_polling_interval = 1000

acceptFrom = *

maxThreads = 0
maxSockets = 0

dedicatedIoThreads = 0

keepAliveIdleTimeout = 7200
busyKeepAliveIdleTimeout = 12


forceHttp10 = auto
# Controls CORS headers sent with responses.  This only takes effect when appServerPorts is set to a non-zero value.
crossOriginSharingPolicy =

allowSslCompression = false
allowSslRenegotiation = true
sendStrictTransportSecurityHeader = false

enableWebDebug = true

allowableTemplatePaths =
enable_risky_command_check = true

loginCustomLogo =
customFavicon =
loginBackgroundImageOption = default
loginCustomBackgroundImage =

loginFooterOption = default
loginFooterText =
loginDocumentTitleOption = default
loginDocumentTitleText =
loginPasswordHint =
appNavReportsLimit = 500
```

When I click the link in our application (`192.1.168.210`)， it invokes splunk java sdk and send request (`http://192.168.1.208/splunk`) to (`http://192.168.1.208/splunk/en-GB/account/login?return_to=%2Fsplunk%2Fen-GB%2F`). I could not find cookie. I even could not enable SSO. How could it be?

I have SSO debug page shown below:

[image]

Comment: So, in your splunk backend (192.168.1.208:8000) you are expecting to see `REMOTE-USER` header with the value capcured from the cookie, correct?

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes, exactly.

Comment: I used your config and I do see the value in 'remote-user' as expected. (for CORS headers you should change `Directory` to `Location`, since proxied path is not on file system).

Comment: @DusanBajic I changed Directory to Location, but I did not succeed. I could not see remote-user in the cookie. Is there something related to rewrite? When apache send the request to  192.168.1.208:8000/splunk, splunk server rewrites to 192.168.1.208:8000/splunk/ /en-GB/account/login?xxx, how to make rewrites in the configuration file httpd-vhost.conf's Location section?

Comment: @DusanBajic Thanks for answer. I updated my configurations and splunk configurations. I could not make Splunk SSO with reverse proxy (apache) work. I still need help

Comment: I can't really see what is wrong. Both your .conf files have `trustedIP = 192.168.1.208` yet your screenshot shows 3 IP addresses? Also maybe try putting only 127.0.0.1 as trusted IP...

Comment: @DusanBajicD You are right. Yesterday I verified the server.conf could only allow 127.0.0.1 as trustedIP. I think the document shall clearly mention that trustedIP could be and only be 127.0.0.1. Now I enabled splunk SSO. But I still have some problem with passing cookie. I believe I could manage. After succeed, I will publish it. Actually I publish how to enable splunk SSO in other thread in stackoverflow.